# including content of other files in php

Tags: php

I have folder `Box`. In that main file `index.php`. 
Now in index.php I am including content of other file which is inside `Box/Wall/insidewall.php`

`insidewall.php` takes image, js from other subfolders in `/Wall`.

I wrote

```
<div style="style=position: relative; margin-top: 200px; margin-left:440px;">
<?php include '/opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2test/Wall/insidewall.php'; ?>
</div>
```

But it shows only content of `insidewall.php` only. Other images, js. css dont reflect.

What mistake I making here?

UPDATE:

directory structure:

insidewall.php is-  https://github.com/karimkhanp/commentbox_quora/blob/master/yepinol/Wall/index.php

The folder `/Wall` I have shifted to somewhere else and trying to include above file with rename `insidewall.php`

Comment: please add that image and js code

Comment: please give code and dir structure

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I added the link for source

Comment: @aligarian: : I added the link for source

Comment: @Programming_crazy same issue, I have already answered, try to use absolute path to include css, js and images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are using sort path to include Images, JS & CSS.

Use `Absolute path` to show all files..

**For Ex.**

```
http://yourdomain.com/fb/stylesheet.css
```

instead of

```
fb/stylesheet.css
```